# Does .NET CORE 3.0 with windows authentication in docker on linux work?

Tags: linux, docker, .net-core, containers

I am trying to enable **windows authentication** using .NET CORE 3.0 application solution in Visual Studio 2019 in docker **linux container** using mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0 image. I can do this setup in IIS windows container without a problem using gMSA account but when it comes to linux container and aspnet:3.0 I am unable to get a prompt for credentials if I use [Authorize] attribute and User.Identity.Name is not populating. I am getting mixed signals from the internet if this is even possible and so far unable to find a concise answer. Just trying different things with registering services JWT/IISDefaults/HttpSysDefaults/Oauth, app.UseAuthentication, Modifying launch settings and app settings.json with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Windows Authentication` inside the Linux container isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps this is the only alternative option as of right now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in a project, and I managed to get the prompt for credentials in ASP.NET like this:
Above the controller you need to authorize access to, put Authorize attribute like this:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "SomeExampleGroup")]
[Route("/some-example")]
public class SomeExampleController : Controller {...}
```

In the ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
services.AddAuthentication(o => o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("SomeExampleGroup",
                        policy => policy.RequireAssertion(/*some assertion here for example*/));
});
```

And in the Configure method make sure to put

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

in this order. Anyway, I managed to get the credentials prompt on Docker in a linux  container like this, but the credentials still won't work, so I hope this helps.